Replace class in span with empty string
I am using a third party component and in the html, there is an element  and I want to remover the k-inner-cell and replace with with an empty string, so that the span has no styling. Can this be done in css or would this have to go thru some javascript? I want to end up with .

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

CSS cannot change an HTML attribute, tho it can change the styling of a particular class. To actually change the attribute you need JS.
